# server output r shiny shows attempt to apply non-function error

Tags: r, dashboard, shinydashboard

I have created a shiny app as follows

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(shinydashboardPlus)
 ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "Visualization tool", titleWidth = "250"),
 dashboardSidebar(width = '250', fluidRow(
 div(numericInput(inputId = "ID", label = "ID1", value = 0, min = 0, max = 
 1000)))),
 dashboardBody(
 fluidRow(column(7,textOutput(outputId = "Table2")))))
 server <- function(input, output) {   
 output$Table2=renderText({
 value=input$ID()
 return(value)
 })}


 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The app has a input box in the sidebar and the number generated should render on the main panel. Hoewevr, I am getting the following error

```
 attempt to apply non-function
```

I am unable to find the issue. request someone to check and suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the error

```
   server <- function(input, output) {   
   output$Table2=renderText({
   value=input$ID
   return(value)
    })}
```